# finding a starting point in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xmldocument

So I have this code.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(location);

XmlNodeList msgSigsNodeList;
try
{
    XmlNode msgSigsNode = document.SelectSingleNode("/sometimesHere/message");
    msgSigsNodeList = msgSigsNode.SelectNodes("whatEver");
}
catch
{
    XmlNode msgSigsNode = document.SelectSingleNode("/message");
    msgSigsNodeList = msgSigsNode.SelectNodes("whatEver");
}
```

but I don't want to use exceptions I would like to use if statements or better yet is there a way to do this without if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. You can use XPath that is independent from root: `//message` (will match any message tag)
2. Start selecting nodes from document root: `document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/message")`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the name of the root node, you should be able to get it via the [`DocumentElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement.aspx) property on `document`:

```
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
```